# Moving a file from one computer into other computer

Tags: java, android

I am a really really new developer. I am currently work a BLE stuff with my friend, but we always have an issue to move my project into his computer, and his project move to my computer.

He does not like to use GitHub at all, me too actually, so we want to just use flash drive to transfer the project folder.(this is the way I found from stackoverflow.com)

I always have errors, and this transfer folder way never work as we respect.
Most of question from "Cannot resolve symbol 'R' such as:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

I already look up online, and most of people just say "clean project", but it does not work at all.

Some of people said, activity_main.xml has problem, but I cant find the problem.

MainActivity.java

```
package test.research.sjsu.beaconbroadcast;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.le.AdvertiseCallback;
import android.bluetooth.le.AdvertiseData;
import android.bluetooth.le.AdvertiseSettings;
import android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeAdvertiser;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.ParcelUuid;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    BluetoothLeAdvertiser mBluetoothLeAdvertiser;
    AdvertiseData mAdvertiseData;
    AdvertiseData.Builder mAdvertiseDataBuilder = new AdvertiseData.Builder();
    byte[] Data = new byte[4];
    ParcelUuid mServiceDataUUID;
    AdvertiseSettings mAdvertiseSettings;
    AdvertiseSettings.Builder mAdvertiseSettingBuilder = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder();
    Button BroadcastButton;
    Button StopBroadcastButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        mBluetoothLeAdvertiser = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();
        Data = hexStringToByteArray("abcdefgh");


            mServiceDataUUID = ParcelUuid.fromString(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

        mAdvertiseDataBuilder.setIncludeDeviceName(true);
        mAdvertiseDataBuilder.setIncludeTxPowerLevel(true);
        mAdvertiseData = mAdvertiseDataBuilder.build();


        mAdvertiseDataBuilder.addServiceData(mServiceDataUUID,Data);
        mAdvertiseSettingBuilder.setAdvertiseMode(1);
        mAdvertiseSettingBuilder.setTimeout(0);
        mAdvertiseSettingBuilder.setTxPowerLevel(2);
        mAdvertiseSettingBuilder.setConnectable(true);
        mAdvertiseSettings = mAdvertiseSettingBuilder.build();
        BroadcastButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BroadcastButton);
        BroadcastButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startAdvertise();
            }
        });
        StopBroadcastButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StopBraodcastButton);
        StopBroadcastButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        StopBroadcastButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                stopAdvertise();
            }
        });

    }
```

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="test.research.sjsu.beaconbroadcast">
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"  android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Sometime there are other red lines, but now the R problem just make me crazy.

Comment: Try SVN if you really hate Github, then you'll like it... You don't even *need* "Github", but using a least `git` + Dropbox, or something would be better than a flash drive

Comment: Your question is missing `activity_main.xml` if you think the problem is there, but it could be in *any XML file* for R.java not to be created

Comment: Are you using Android Studio?

Comment: Yeah, I am using Android Studio 3.0 Canary 4. I dont know where the problem is, but I just hear the problem could be in xml file. I dont know how to check all.